# Azure pipeline failing with "Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Getting the Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision error. I have added the "'args: '-UseModernBuildSystem=0'" even then facing the same issue.

```
      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: 'cert.p12'
          certPwd: '$(certpasswd)'

      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        inputs:
          provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
          provProfileSecureFile: 'app_profile.mobileprovision'

      - task: Xcode@5
        displayName: 'Xcode Development Release'
        inputs:
          actions: 'archive'
          sdk: '$(sdk)'
          scheme: '$(scheme)'
          xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj'
          exportOptions: 'specify'
          exportMethod: 'app-store'
          archivePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build/iOSApp.xcarchive'
          exportPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build/output'
          teamId: '$(TeamId)'
          exportTeamId: '$(ExportTeamId)'
          packageApp: true
          signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
          provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
          args: '-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
      
      - task: AppStoreRelease@1
        inputs:
          serviceEndpoint: '$(ServiceEndpoint)'
          appIdentifier: '$(AppIdentifier)'
          appType: 'iOS'
          releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
          shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
          shouldSkipSubmission: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `embedded.mobileprovision` exists and the file location. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015902/13464420), the file needs to exist in root of folder. If it doesn't exist, you could use Copy file task to copy the file to the root before packing.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
            contents: '**/*.ipa'
            targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
    inputs:
        authType: 'UserAndPass'
        username: '$(user)'
        password: '$(pass)'
        appIdentifier: 'App Identifier'
        appType: 'iOS'
        ipaPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa'
        releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
        teamId: 'Team ID'
        teamName: 'Team Name'
        fastlaneArguments: 'action increment_build_number'
```

In addition, here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336059/issues-with-publishing-ios-app-to-testflight-through-azure-devops) with the same issue you can refer to.

Comment: I have checked and found that the embedded.mobileprovision is not present

Comment: I tried copying the file to the root of folder still experiencing the same error

Answer (score 0):

It probably was caused by your ipa not being correctly signed.  The default value of `signingOption` property is `nosign`. if you didnot specifically assign a value to `signingOption` of Xcode. You ipa will not be signed. So if your ipa needs to be signed. You need to assign `manual` or `auto` to `signingOption` property. See this more Xcode task Arguments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops#arguments).

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    .....
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

Please check examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops#signing-and-provisioning).