# What is the "Distributions" section of .xcarchives Info.plist used for?

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution, xcarchive

Recent Xcode versions started to put "Distributions" key/value into .xcarchives Info.plist file.

What is it used for?
Can I remove it before signing?
Is there even a definition/documentation of keys in this Info.plist?

(example of this .plist can be seen in this issue: [Issues with publishing iOS app to testflight through Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336059/issues-with-publishing-ios-app-to-testflight-through-azure-devops))

Thanks